# Use input to set a list of all characters. Use list length to check & replace all characters with corresponding value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, str-replace

I'm working on a conversion code that needs to take a user input & split the string into a list of each/all characters. I want to set a variable value to the length of the list & check if each item exists. For this, my code is...

```
txtIn = str(input('Enter string: '))
s = list(txtIn)
l = len(s)
```

I also have a dictionary set as follows..
    binNum = {
        '1': '1',
        '2': '10',
        '3': '11'
        }

What I want to do is check each value of the user set list using the length, to change the value of each character. How I want this to look is the user inputs: 123. It will check the created list for '1' then replace it with its corresponding value. It will then check for the next character ('2') once the previous character has been found & replaced. Am I right in thinking that I would have to set some kind of temporary variable to hold the compare value & pass the value along after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily without any temporary variables:

```
txtIn = input('Enter string: ')
binNum = { '1': '1', '2': '10', '3': '11' }

print(''.join([binNum.get(x, x) for x in txtIn]))
```

This uses a list comprehension with dictionary `get` to get the value corresponding and then `join`.

---

For a true binary conversion, you can use `format` or `f`-strings:

```
txtIn = int(input('Enter string: '))

print("{0:b}".format(txtIn))
# or print(f'{txtIn:b}')
```

Comment: That's perfect for what I'm trying to do, however it will only allow 0-9. How could I implement this in a way that 1 would print as 1 {'1': '1'} but 11 would be {'11': '1011'}. At the moment the output gives '11' as ' 1 1' rather than 1011 as in my list. It's for binary so I'm sure that should help understanding the format I need. Appreciate the help you've already given too.

Comment: Both this answer and mine translate from decimal to BCD (binary coded decimal). What you need is a translation from decimal to true binary. A character by character translation is not suitable for this problem. You need to use a decimal to binary translation algorithm.

Comment: @BenjaminHoving, There is this translation algo built in to python `format`.

Comment: @Austin Yup. I guess I have never needed to use the binary format spec before. Not sure what OP wants for negative numbers or if that is even a consideration, but format just tacks a `'-'` onto the front of the string if the number is negative. Could just run it through abs first if necessary.

Comment: @BenjaminHoving I understand there may be some built in functions, I am still learning python & I would like to hard code just for my own educational purposes.

Comment: @Bl1xY, You can just hard code things only if you can distinguish 1 and 11 from your input.

Comment: @Austin I think I may have just sussed it by using s = txtIn.split(' ') then used the first answer 'for x in s'. As far as I can see it appears to be what I want. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: @Bl1xY You will need to provide a hardcoded translation for every possible number with that method. (If I understand what you are saying correctly.)

Comment: @Benjamin Hoving Yes I think we are thinking the same thing but I do understand I will need to (to an extent) mostly all can be done fairly quickly using Kali Crunch or SED etc, I'm just trying to get familiar with basic data handling, functions & variables/values.

Answer (score 0):

OP wants true binary translation as opposed to BCD conversion. This answer provides BCD conversion.

Here is a method using the built-in `str.translate`method.

```
binNum = { '1': '1', '2': '10', '3': '11' }
translationTable = {ord(ch): result for ch, result in binNum.items()}
txtIn = input('Enter string: ')
txtOut = txtIn.translate(translationTable)
print(txtOut)
```